# How to grab deepest nested object in json JS

Tags: javascript, json

Is it possible to get the deepest level object without knowing path names?

for example I have this json

```js
 const response = {
            level1: {
               level2: {
                  level3: {responseObject}
                       }
                    }
                  }
```

the levels will always only contain 1 value
but the there may be varying levels of nesting(5max)

is there anyway to alway get to the response object without using something such as response.level1.level2.level3?

note: the response object will always have the same keys

Comment: When do you know to stop traversing? If `responseObject` is itself an object, how would you know to not delve into its properties?

Comment: great question, ill add that the response object is always has the same keys

Answer (score 2):

Use a recursive search

1. Check if the object matches the key template for a response object (*"the response object will always have the same keys"*)
2. If so, you've found the response object so return it
3. If not, search again with the first object value (since *"the levels will always only contain 1 value"*)
4. If any level search is on a non-object, bail out

```js
const response = {
  level1: {
    level2: {
      level3: {
        I: "am",
        a: "response object"
      }
    }
  }
}

const responseObjectKeyTemplate = (["I", "a"]).sort().join(",")
const isResponseObject = (obj) =>
  Object.keys(obj).sort().join(",") === responseObjectKeyTemplate
  
const searchLevel = (obj) => {
  if (typeof obj !== "object") {
    return null // not an object, bail
  }
  if (isResponseObject(obj)) {
    return obj // found it
  }
  
  // BWAAAAAAA (Inception pun)
  return searchLevel(Object.values(obj)[0])
}

console.log(searchLevel(response))
```